# Starting wealth for Complete classes

Tags: dnd-3.5e, character-creation, wealth

Does D&D 3.5e have official random starting wealth tables for the classes given in the Complete supplements? I know there's a table for the core classes in the Player Handbook, but I can't find an equivalent table in the Complete books.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OK, decided to look into this.

There are no nice, neat tables that I can find. That said, the actual information does appear to be available, excepting for the Wu Jen.

*Complete Adventurer* is the most straight-forward: it’s included in each class’s entry as **Starting Gold**.

*Complete Warrior* neglected starting wealth entirely, but it’s included in the [official Errata](https://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/CompleteWarrior_Errata08022005.zip). Since the Errata is free, I think it’s safe to reproduce that here:

> Hexblade: 6d4×10 gp
>
> Samurai: 2d4×10 gp
>
> Swashbuckler: 6d4×10 gp

It’s always a good idea to check the [Errata](https://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/er/20040125a). Wizards has made some hilarious mistakes (my favorite is when they neglected to include *any DCs at all* in *Tome of Magic* for an entire type of Truenaming check), so the Errata is good to know.

For *Complete Arcane*, I can’t find any direct note of the starting wealth, and it doesn’t appear to be in the Errata. However, the Warlock and Warmage “Starting Packages” each have starting money in addition to equipment. I believe the rule is, you take the Starting Package’s starting money after items, and multiply it by 10. The Wu Jen doesn’t have a Starting Package that I can see, however.

*Complete Divine* is like *Complete Arcane*, but all of the classes have a Starting Package.

## Weird Page on Wizards’ Website

I just found [this page](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/ebmoh/20050311), which, among other things, has this:

> #### Errata
>
> **Q: The Mark of Heroes Campaign Standards Table CS—2 has no entry for artificers’ starting gold. My guess is 200 gp, as artificers get 5d4 x10 starting gold (Eberron Campaign Setting page 33), and it seems that characters get the maximum starting gold for their class. Is this right?**
>
> A: Yes it is. In fact that’s true for all the other classes not currently listed on Table CS—2. Of course this is extremely difficult to determine for classes from most of the “Complete” books, because the random starting gold for all but the scout class were omitted. For ease, here is the complete list of starting gold for the artificer class and the classes unlocked by Campaign Cards.
>
> ```
> CLASS          | STARTING GOLD
> ---------------+--------------
> Artificer      |        200 gp
> Favored Soul   |        200 gp
> Psion          |        120 gp
> Psychic Warrior|        200 gp
> Scout          |        200 gp
> Soulknife      |        200 gp
> Swashbuckler   |        200 gp
> Warmage        |        120 gp
> Wilder         |        160 gp
> ```

(omitted: some asterisks indicating some details relevant only to the “Mark of Heroes” campaign)

Since for this “Mark of Heroes” campaign, everyone gets maximum gold, 200 gp seems to be 5d4×10 gp, 160 gp is 4d4×10 gp, and 120 gp is 3d4×10 gp.

Maybe that seems “more official” but since this page is for some weird product (cards to “unlock” races and classes?) that I’ve never heard of, I’m not sure what to make of it.

Comment: +1 I've not found what you're talking about with the starting package money multiplier, though.

Comment: @LitheOhm: I could not either, but looking at the classes that had Starting Packages *and* Starting Wealth, it seemed to hold true. I know it's what I was told to do at one point, but it might be a "rule of thumb" more than an official rule.

Comment: Warmage was originally introduced in the Miniatures Handbook. Starting gp is listed as 3d4x10.

Comment: Huh. I didn't know any other answer even mentioned campaign cards. I guess I should link from here to [here](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/85130/8610).