# What's up with RPGA Living Campaign player rewards cards?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, forgotten-realms, eberron, greyhawk, organized-play

The Wizards of the Coast archives host the following RPGA Living Campaign player reward cards:

- [*Living Greyhawk*](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=lg/welcome) (3/2003 to 6/2008): [Set 1](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=lg/dndlg/20070529a), [Set 2](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=lg/dndlg/20071127a), and [Set 3](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=lg/dndlg/20071127b).
- [*Legacy of the Green Regent*](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/archfr/frgr) (5/2003 to 7/2005): [Set 1](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/frgr/20030905a), [Set 2](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/frgr/20030905b), [Set 3](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/frgr/20031105a), [Set 4](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/frgr/20040326a), and [Set 5](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/frgr/20040702a).
- [*Mark of Heroes*](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/archeb/ebmoh) (11/2003 to 3/2006): [Set 1](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/ebmoh/20041129d), [Set 2](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/ebmoh/20050414a), [Set 3](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/ebmoh/20050701a), [Set 4](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/ebmoh/20051024a), and [Set 5](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/ebmoh/20060206a), and [promo cards](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/ebmoh/20041129e).
- [*Xen'drik Expeditions*](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/ebxe/welcome) (2/2006 to 9/2007): [Set 1](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/ebxe/20061009a), [Set 2](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/ebxe/20070528a), [Set 3](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/ebxe/20071126a), [Set 4](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/ebxe/20071126a&page=2), and [promo cards](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/ebxe/20060224a).
- At least two other promo cards exist: [Wilderness Survivor](https://www.nobleknight.com/imagepage.asp?image=wildernesssurvivorcard.jpg&name=Player%20Rewards%20Card%202%20-%20Wilderness%20Survivor) and [Dungeon Delver](https://www.nobleknight.com/imagepage.asp?image=dungeondelvercard.jpg&name=Player%20Rewards%20Card%201%20-%20Dungeon%20Delver), but I can't determine their provenance.

I've never played in a living campaign outside of classic [*Spycraft*](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/48297/8610), so I have some questions about these cards.

1. Are there more cards than are listed here, and are they freely and legally available?
2. How were these cards distributed by the publisher? To the players?
3. How were these cards used during play?

I am specifically interested in experiences with *Dungeons and Dragons 3.5* (as that's the system with which I'm considering using them). I am *not* interested in the acquisition, distribution, and use of player rewards cards for earlier edition (if any exist) and later editions (which I know they do).

---

***"Who cares?"***: Some of the special abilities the cards grant are interesting and worth a feat, and I'm considering making such abilities available as feats in my home campaign, but before I do I'd like to know how common these special abilities were among Living Campaign adventurers (hence the question about distribution) and how the cards were used so I don't accidentally implode the campaign by offering some card abilities as feats (hence the question about use).

Answer (score 9):

Those were part of the organized play program. They weren't intended for home game use, per se, but earning them in play at RPGA events allowed using them in later ones. I remember them being awarded as prizes for either participation and/or successful completion of events, but I wasn't active in the programs at the time.

According to the Living Greyhawk Campaign Standards, they were use-once-per-adventure rewards, and the number used per character was level limited.. (LGCS 597 v 7.5, page 18.)

> #### Out-of-Game Benefit Rules
>
> Each player may use one of the benefits listed below for
>   every four levels (round up) that their PC possesses (cohorts
>   have no bearing on this calculation). For example, the
>   player of a 3rd-level PC may use one benefit, while the
>   player of a 9th-level PC may use three.
>
> No button or card may be used more than once in any
>   adventure, regardless of the number of rounds. You must
>   select your benefits to be used and show them to the GM
>   before the start of the adventure. Benefits may be loaned to
>   other players at the table at the beginning of the session.
>   Benefits are not destroyed when used and can be used again
>   in future sessions. No more than one benefit can be used to
>   affect a single roll, except where the benefit specifically
>   allows for such use.

[Living Greyhawk Campaign Standards (www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=lg/welcome)](http://www.wizards.com/default.asp?x=lg/welcome)

Comment: There were buttons, too?! (Thank you, by the way. That limit by level makes them much more interesting.)

Comment: The buttons worked just like the cards. I've seen only one button.

Comment: IIRC, there were 4 buttons with pictures of 4 stock 3.5 characters on them but they all did the same thing, +1 to a d20 roll.  The LGCS linked gives the names of the characters (but not the bonus) page 18 (as well as the legal cards for Living Greyhawk).

Comment: I'm back on this project, and I want to accept this answer, but one point's confusing me. Some of the later cards say they count as two cards in a player's stack. Is there *both* a limit to the size of a player's stack *and* a limit on how many cards he can play during an adventure? Would that mean a player that used one double-counting card to create his PC couldn't use another card during an adventure until his PC was level 9 or higher?

Comment: @HeyICanChan I don't believe any of those cards were legal in LG (assuming you're going based around the LGCS rules as in this answer) but on creation of a kobold (required a card) you indeed could not have another reward card until level 5 (next reward card "slot").  Sorry I never played in any of the campaigns other than LG so unsure their rules.

Answer (score 5):

RE2) The cards were distributed by the publisher via mail for rewards for judging in or hosting events (as evidenced by the (now dead) rewards link in many of the links in the Q).  Each time you judged or hosted, you provided your RPGA number (since generalized by WotC to a system generic number) and received a number of points for your efforts.  When you accumulated a certain number by a mailing period (I think quarterly?), you'd be mailed rewards (they had your address from the aforementioned RPGA number registration).  In addition to those cards (which were the most common) they also gave away some templates (such as http://www.trollandtoad.com/p291091.html).  The more points you got, the more rewards you got (mostly additional cards).  As far as I could tell cards received were randomized (for there were some I did not have).  I recall vaguely people getting complete sets at once but I am not sure that was out of the rewards program (though I have a faint recollection this was from having enough points - reward = avoiding randomidity).

RE1) To my memory/knowledge there was no legalese against trading or giving these away (outside of the table/round; you had to lock down which you were using when the round started).  I've heard about folks selling them and buying them online, though that was a while ago.

I believe the button referenced by @aramis was given away at a larger convention (GenCon?) and not as the reward system.  I never owned one but was active in living campaigns when the reward system started, thus my belief (and also apparently 8-13 year old memories;p).

RE3 and general) I gave @aramis a +1 because as far as I recall/know everything he said is accurate.  Just adding additional information that I recall.